# error when checking for nil in CKAsset

Tags: swift, cloudkit

I'm working with CloudKit and when loading data I'm checking in code if CKAsset is nil or not such as:

```
let img = result.value(forKey: "Picture") as! CKAsset
if  img != nil {

}
```

and getting following error:

> "Comparing non-optional value type 'CKAsset' to nil always returns true

I know it has something to do with optionals but not able to find solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`img` can't be `nil` because you are force-casting it to `CKAsset`. Of course your app will crash at runtime if `result.value(forKey: "Picture")` returns `nil` or it's not actually a `CKAsset`.

The proper way to code this is follows:

```
if let img = result.value(forKey: "Picture") as? CKAsset {
    // do something with img
} else {
    // there is no Picture value or it's not actually a CKAsset
}
```